# ZODB 3 for 64 bit windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, 64-bit, zope, zodb

I tried to install ZODB3 for 64 bit Python 2.7 with pip. This installation requires a local compiler to compile the BTrees extension. As I do not have the needed MS compiler installed:

- Is there a binary 64 bit Windows installer for ZODB on Python 2.7 ? I used Google but did not succeed
- Is BTrees really required or can I install ZODB3 without BTrees ?

Cherrs, Uwe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ZODB3 package comes with pre-compiled eggs for Windows, see the [PyPI page for ZODB3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB3/3.10.5).

You need to tell `pip` explicitly that it needs to install an egg; it normally does not support installing from an egg:

```
pip install --egg ZODB3
```

Alternatively, you could use `easy_install` instead.

Comment: My pip v 1.1 has no --egg option, the website of pip does not mention this flag too. But using easy_install is the solution !

Comment: @rocksportrocker: It was added in pip 1.2.

Comment: hmm, I am browsing http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html which is about v 1.2.1, but this site does not mention --egg too, maybe the docs are not up to date. I try to upgrade my pip. Thanks.

Comment: @rocksportrocker: `pip install --help` lists it, and I verified what it does in the source. It essentially runs `easy_install ZODB3` when using that option. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Struggling with ZODB3 easy_install/pip/compiler woes on Windows? Try Christoph Gohlke's "Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages" download page:

- 64 and 32 bit ZODB3 binaries packaged as .exe installers are available for python 2.5/2.6/2.7: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#zodb3
- You will need to run the appropriate zope.interface installer from the same source first: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#Zope.interface